# command not found after setting path correctly in bash

Tags: bash

I have set path correctly just like before but I am getting command not found error.

```
$echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin/node
```

So I have to run node using full path for every run and it always gives error of Permission denied when run without sudo:

```
$sudo /usr/local/bin/node ***
```

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shorten your `$PATH` from `/usr/local/bin/node` to `/usr/local/bin`.

The `$PATH` variable is for storing the names of directories which contain executables; it's **not** for storing any names of executables *within* those directories.  The `file` command will show the difference:

```
file /usr/local/bin /usr/local/bin/node
```

The `sudo` trouble probably means that the current user lacks permission to run `node`.  Check permission and ownership:

```
stat --printf="%a %G:%U\n" /usr/local/bin/node
```

It should say something like:

```
777  root:root
```

Suppose it doesn't, but there's another file `foo` in `usr/local/bin/` that works every time, and has the correct permissions and ownership.  To give `node` the same permissions and ownership as `foo`:

```
sudo chown --reference=/usr/local/bin/foo /usr/local/bin/node
sudo chmod --reference=/usr/local/bin/foo /usr/local/bin/node
```